# How to choose the $c$ term when evaluating the error of a Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, approximation

I was looking at this link ([https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~CLP/CLP1/clp_1_dc/ssec_taylor_error.html](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7ECLP/CLP1/clp_1_dc/ssec_taylor_error.html)) which shows how to calculate the error of a Taylor series based on how many terms you wish to include in the approximation:

[image]

Regarding the error of the Taylor approximation, everything in the above formula looks relatively straightforward. I am just not sure how to select a value of $c$. This indicates that $c$ should be between $a$ (the point at which you are approximating the function with the Taylor series) and $x$ (the point at which you are evaluating the approximation of the Taylor series at).

But apart from this, is there some standard method of selecting $c$?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this sounds like a "stupid question" - but is there some way of showing that : the more terms you include in your Taylor Approximation, the smaller the error becomes?

Comment: In general we do not know the value of $c$. What we know is that there is a $c$ between $a$ and $x$ so that 3.4.33 holds. To bound the error term, one usually obtains a uniform estimate for $f^{(n+1)}(t)$ for any $t$ between $a$ and $x$, and this will in particular hold for $t=c$ as well.

Comment: @ Gary: thank you! does this mean that the choice of "c" is somewhat irrelevant when calculating the error?

Comment: It is relevant in the sense that you know on which interval you have to bound the derivative as I described above. You may find [this](https://wp.ufpel.edu.br/zahn/files/2017/01/taylor_formula.pdf) paper interesting as well.

Comment: @ Gary: thank you so much!